# How Create a Flat, Long Shadow range in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, function, range, shadow

I want to create a range slider `text-shadow` like this:

```
text-shadow: rgb(18, 128, 106) 1px 1px,
    text-shadow: rgb(18, 128, 106) 1px 1px,                                                                                            
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 2px 2px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 3px 3px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 4px 4px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 5px 5px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 6px 6px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 7px 7px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 8px 8px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 9px 9px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 10px 10px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 11px 11px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 12px 12px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 13px 13px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 14px 14px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 15px 15px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 16px 16px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 17px 17px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 18px 18px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 19px 19px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 20px 20px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 21px 21px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 22px 22px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 23px 23px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 24px 24px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 25px 25px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 26px 26px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 27px 27px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 28px 28px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 29px 29px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 30px 30px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 31px 31px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 32px 32px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 33px 33px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 34px 34px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 35px 35px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 36px 36px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 37px 37px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 38px 38px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 39px 39px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 40px 40px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 41px 41px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 42px 42px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 43px 43px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 44px 44px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 45px 45px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 46px 46px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 47px 47px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 48px 48px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 49px 49px,
    rgb(18, 128, 106) 50px 50px;
```

With this jQuery code :

```
$('#Range').change(function () {
    $('.divwidth').css({ boxShadow: this.value + 'px' });
});
```

this.value = value of range.

HTML:

```
<input type="range" name="amountRange" id="Range" value="250" min="0" max="500" step="1" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value" />
<input type="text" name="amountInput" id="textnumber" min="0" max="500" step="1" value="250" oninput="this.form.amountRange.value=this.value" /><span>px</span>
```

Comment: So, when an `input` element's value has changed, you want to generate/apply a range of `box-shadow`s? From `0px 0px` to what value? The value of the changed `input`?

Comment: i want whit html range change the text-shadow px change whit range input

Comment: And what HTML have you got to work with? Incidentally, don't post *all* of your code, we didn't need every single one of the hundred lines of repeated code. Abbreviate, and make your code concise.

Comment: i want create something like this http://sandbox.juan-i.com/longshadows/

Comment: Great, so what's your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you want something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zgy4uxLp/), though it isn't completely clear because you use box-shadow and text-shadow in your text.

```
$("input").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("input").not(this).val(val);
    $("#the-text").css({"textShadow":"rgb(18, 128, 106) "+val+"px "+ val+"px"});
});
```

Comment: Thank you its greate bu iwant create something like this http://sandbox.juan-i.com/longshadows/

Answer (score 0):

here is the fiddle

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/q62whjre/1/)

i was not sure what you wanted `box-shadow` or `text-shadow` so created both in the fiddle i have created 3 `range`  `x-axis` `y-axis` and `blur` for `box shadow`

```
function boxshadow() {
        a = $('#Range').val() + 'px'
        b = $('#Range1').val() + 'px'
        c = $('#Range2').val() + 'px'

        $('.test').css({ 'box-shadow': a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + '#888888'})

        $('.text').css({ 'text-shadow': a + ' ' + b +' ' + '#FF0000'})
}

boxshadow()

$('input[type=range]').on('change', function () {
    boxshadow()
})
```

Comment: for the start i want create a text Flat, Long Shadow slide With html range but i am do not understand how a started With my code if you can show how i started With my code , I would be very happy :)